# Short|quick int values comparison

Tags: java, validation, if-statement, comparison

I learned about terminary expression, but what I want is a little different.

I have the following:

```
int MODE = getMyIntValue();
```

I do comparison as the following:

```
if(MODE == 1 || MODE == 2 || MODE == 3) //do something
```

I would like to know if there is a short way of doing this, I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
if(MODE == 1 || 2 || 3) //do something
```

There is a short|quick way of doing it? I like quick "ifs" because it makes the code more clear, for example, it is more clear this:

```
System.out.println(MODE == 1 ? text1 : text2):
```

Than this:

```
if(MODE == 1) System.out.println(text1):

else System.out.println(text1):
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind the boxing hit, you could use a set which you prepared earlier:

```
// Use a more appropriate name if necessary
private static final Set<Integer> VALID_MODES
    = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

...

if (VALID_MODES.contains(mode)) {
}
```

You could use an `int[]` and a custom "does this array contain this value" method if you wanted... it would be O(N) or O(log N) for a binary search, but I suspect we're talking about small sets anyway.

Comment: There sould be HashSer<Integer> shouldn't be? However, thank you, worked like I expected (y)

Comment: @Murillo: Not if you're using Java 7 - it's the "diamond operator" (not actually an operator, but...)

Answer (score 2):

May be you can do something like this

```
System.out.println(Mode == 1 ? "1" : Mode == 2 ? "2" : "3");
```

[switch-case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) also makes code more readable than multiple if-else

Comment: Hmm, it worked, but I can get better use of what Jon Skeet suggested, but your aswer is really good and simple too, +1

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use a more typed approach:

```
public class QuickIntSample {

enum Modes {
    ONE(1),TWO(2),THREE(3); // you may choose more useful and readable names
    
    int code;
    private Modes(int code)  {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static Modes fromCode(final int intCode) {
        for (final Modes mode : values()) {
            if (mode.code == intCode) {
                return mode;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
} // -- END of enum


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int mode = 2;

    if( Modes.fromCode(mode) == Modes.TWO ) {
        System.out.println("got code 2");
    }

}

}
```